# How to run ODI12c mapping from bash to automate ODI mapping process

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse

We have created ODI12c(12.2.1.2.6) mapping to load data from external table to staging table and staging table to fact table.
Our database is oracle 19c.
Now, we would like to automate ETL process by running ODI mapping from AIX 7.2 crontab to do schedule odi mapping run.
Would you please help us how to run odi mapping from AIX 7.2 crontab

Comment: What specific issue do you have with running ODI from a command line?

Comment: I would like to run ODI scenario to automate ETL process